# Error when running JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I finished a Java game I was working on. **Tried to run it by double clicking the icon, didn't run. It runs fine in Eclipse.**

Tried to run it from the command line. Gave me a `NullPointerException`, on some image resource I have in a folder called sprites in the src folder, inside Eclipse.

For some reason, when running it outside Eclipse, it doesn't find this resource.

Any suggestions?

#### EDIT

I use Windows XP. The IDE is Eclipse. Inside Eclipse, as I said, there's no problem.
I use the following command to use the image resources:

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/sprites/picture.PNG").getImage();
```

I checked inside the JAR, all resources are inside.

`sprites` is a folder inside `src`. So as far as I see, it should work. What's the problem?

Comment: You might want to check in your .jar (which is basically a zipped folder) for your resources.

Comment: probably the path is wrong ;) did you check if the image is inside the jar and the path is pointing at the right location?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using to load this image?

Comment: OS? Exact command to run it? Content listing of the Jar? All completely unimportant, it seems ....

Answer (score 1):

If your sources are like that :

```
/src 
  /mypackage
      /myresourcespackage
          - Resources.java
          - image.png
```

You can load `image.png` using :

```
ImageIO.read(Resources.class.getResource("image.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`. When you specify a path for the image using this method, the **path is relative to the MyClass.class *compiled* file**. Not your .java file, or your project directory.

For example if your file system looks like this:

```
+ Project Folder
|
-> + src
|  |
|  -> MyClass.java
|
-> + bin
   |
   -> MyClass.class
   -> myImage.png
```

Then you would use the following code to retrieve the `BufferedImage` from `myImage.png`:

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myImage.png");
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(stream);
```

Remember, when using the `getResourceAsStream()` method, you *must* specify the path relative to the .class file, NOT the .java file. Many IDE's put them in separate places.

You can get as advanced as you want to with the file system, but just make sure all your paths are right.
For example, if your file system looked like this:

```
+ Project Folder
|
-> + src
|  |
|  -> MyClass.java
|
-> + bin
   |
   -> MyClass.class
   -> + Sprites
      |
      -> + Images
         |
         -> myImage.png
```

You would just change the file path from `myImage.png` to `Sprites/Images/myImage.png"`. Note the use of the file extension and the lack of a leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If the resource file is packaged into the jar file use

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` or `Class.getResourceAsStream`

They are definitely the way to go for loading the resource data from classpath.

Comment: what's wrong with this.getClass.getResource("/sprites/file.PNG")?

Comment: check if the file is included into the jar (jar is a zip). Remove the starting /